# Why is addBack used with Find()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand what does this code do and why have we used addBack() with find() when the same results are obtained without using addBack()

Take these two examples

```
$("body div").find("*").addBack().contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3 && /shaolin/i.test(this.nodeValue);
})
```

vs

```
$("#myDiv").find("*").addBack().contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3 && /judo/i.test(this.nodeValue);
})
```

Also why are we doing /shaolin/i.test(this.nodeValue);?

Comment: Who is this "we"? And without further context, we'd all be guessing.

Comment: I am just trying to search some HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find()` only returns the descendants that match the selector. The code uses `addBack` so that it will also search the contents of the original `body div` elements, in addition to all their descendants.

If none of the top-level `DIV` elements match the filter function, then the result will be the same with or without the `addBack`. The code is trying to be thorough, so it won't miss anything.

The code is looking for all text nodes within `body div` that contain the word `shaolin`. `/shaolin` is a regular expression, and it tests each text node's value against this.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/addback/):

> .addBack() add the previous set of elements on the stack to the
>   current set, optionally filtered by a selector.

In your case, the `addBack()` add any `div` inside your `body` to the current set which is any element that are the children of any `div`.

So it's not only find the contents of an element placed under a `div` but also the `div` contents itself.